# Why is systemd stopping service immediately after it is started?

Tags: linux, systemd

I created a systemd service which should invoke a shell script, when started or on reboot.

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the DCCA index software

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/insiteone/bin/indexControl start
ExecStop=/opt/insiteone/bin/indexControl stop

# Execute pre and post scripts as root
#PermissionsStartOnly=true
Restart=on-abort
TimeoutSec=600
```

Initially it kept on restarting in infinite loop as soon as it is started, but when i added the `TimeoutSec` option, it called the `ExecStop` as soon as the service was started for the first time (started, and then stopped again immediately).

Any clue, where i am going wrong?
P.S: indexControl is a shell script, which starts other processes.

Comment: `chkconfig index off` is of no help as well (index.service is the ssystemd service file)

Comment: I got the answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/1022142/why-is-systemd-stopping-service-immediately-after-it-is-started which fixed the issue

Answer (score 7):

Try changing `Restart=on-abort` to `Restart=on-abnormal`

From http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html:

> Setting this to on-failure is the recommended choice for long-running
>   services, in order to increase reliability by attempting automatic
>   recovery from errors. For services that shall be able to terminate on
>   their own choice **(and avoid immediate restarting)**, on-abnormal is
>   an alternative choice.

Also, you may want to add `Type=oneshot` to the `[Service]` section.

From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Service_types:

> Type=oneshot: this is useful for scripts that do a single job and then
>   exit. You may want to set RemainAfterExit=yes as well so that systemd
>   still considers the service as active after the process has exited.

You can paste my recommended changes below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the DCCA index software

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/insiteone/bin/indexControl start
ExecStop=/opt/insiteone/bin/indexControl stop
Restart=on-abnormal
```

Something else to consider is whether or not you even need the `Restart=` line ... Does the script this service file calls fail often?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `type=oneshot` does not work, but `type=forking` does. I got the answer from here, which works. http://superuser.com/questions/1022142/why-is-systemd-stopping-service-immediately-after-it-is-started/

Comment: With RemainAfterExit=yes and Type=oneshot maybe work

Comment: Cannot set `Restart=on-abnormal` on **oneshot** services, only `Restart=no` is allowed:
`Service has Restart= setting other than no, which isn't allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.`

Comment: @AkisC Your suggestion for RemainAfterExit=yes and Type=oneshot worked! Thanks